# Maven build as GitLab artifact is being ignored by following jobs

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline where the first 2 stages are one for the *build* and one for *unit tests*, on a Maven project.

The two stages can be summarized with the following commands:

- [build] `mvn -s ci/settings.xml test-compile`
- [unit_tests] `mvn -s ci/settings.xml verify`

When running them on a local machine, the first one prints:

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 133 source files to <mydir>
```

while the second one, given that the project was already built, prints:

```
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
```

and this is the expected behavior on GitLab too.

**What happens on GitLab, however, is that the *unit tests* stage prints the very same thing as the build one, meaning that it's not correctly using the artifact that I exported in the previous stage.**

This is the *build* job:

```
build:
  stage: build
  image: maven:3.6-jdk-11
  script:
    - 'mvn -s ci/settings.xml test-compile'
  except:
    - tags
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/
```

This job ends with the following log:

```
Uploading artifacts...
target/: found 226 matching files and directories  
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... ok  id=1964 responseStatus=201 Created token=qwYzjEeM
```

meaning that the *target* folder has been uploaded correctly.

This is the *unit tests* job:

```
junit:
  stage: unit_tests
  script:    
    - 'mvn -s ci/settings.xml verify'
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit:
        - target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
```

This job starts with the following log:

```
Downloading artifacts for build (1964)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=1964 responseStatus=200 OK token=qwYzjEeM
```

meaning that the *target* folder was correctly received (I also added an `ls -la target` to see if files were there and they seemed right).

**Given that artifacts seem to be uploaded/downloaded correctly, why does the *unit tests* job rebuild the entire project?**

Comment: I don't know why this gitlab directory moving fails, but why do you do it in the first place? Why not just run `verify`?

Comment: It's a pipeline I inherited and I can't change its steps as a lot of projects depend on this template. Also, there are more maven steps after the JUnit one and they would have the very same problem as this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in the end the issue is caused by both how *GitLab* restores the artifacts and by how `git clone` works.

Basically *GitLab* will preserve artifact's last modified timestamp, while `git clone` won't.

This leads to the following scenario:

1. `git clone` is executed, and now all the files in the `src` directory have the current timestamp
2. *GitLab* extracts the artifact archive and preserves the timestamps, so now files in the `target` directory have the timestamp that they had in the previous CI job
3. This means that files in the `target` directory will look older than files in the `src` one, and this triggers a full recompile in Maven

The issue has been reported to *GitLab* and can be tracked [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/234078).

A temporary workaround is to manually create the artifact archive and manually extract it once the other job begins.

This is a sample pipeline that's used as a workaround (the `-DD` option is the one that doesn't preserve timestamps when extracting, which is what makes this workaround actually work):

```
.prepare-build-artifact: &prepare-build-artifact |
  apt update && apt install -y zip
  zip -r -q target.zip target/

.extract-build-artifact: &extract-build-artifact |
  unzip -DD -q target.zip

build:
  stage: build
  image: maven:3.6-jdk-11
  script:
    - 'mvn test-compile'
    - *prepare-build-artifact
  except:
    - tags
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target.zip

junit:
  stage: unit_tests
  script:
    - *extract-build-artifact
    - 'mvn verify'
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit:
        - target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
```